# text attributes for individual terms in rST math markup

Tags: math, restructuredtext

Can individual terms in rST-based math markup be made bold? I'd like to apply boldface and perhaps other attributes (e.g., color, font) to some, but not all, terms in a :math: expression. I'll continue to experiment, as I couldn't find the answer.  Using rST in a sphinx environment. Thanks...